# Logstash will continue from unprocessed line?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

10 CSV files have 200 k records And run the file through command line with below mentioned input configuration,

```
D:\www\logstash-6.2.3\bin>logstash -f D:\www\logstash-6.2.3\conf\sample-csv.conf  --debug
```

Input Configuration:

```
input {                                                                                             
  file {
     path => "D:/ELK-Sample-CSV/pr/pr_*.csv"
     start_position => "beginning"
     sincedb_path => "D:/www/logstash-6.2.3/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_*"
   }
}
```

- If I suddenly stop my logstash after some amount of data imported( ex: 50k records imported)

  ```
  index           docs.count      docs.deleted
  data-pr          4000           0
  ```
- Then run again the same file,

  ```
  First time imported 50 k records
  Now, have to import the unprocessed line (from 50001 to 200k)
  ```

So, how to config my input?

After Restart :

```
index           docs.count      docs.deleted
data-pr          12857          2456
```

**docs.count** increasing and also **docs.deleted** counts increasing.

Comment: Yes, logstash will continue from the first unprocessed line. If you set `sincedb_path => /dev/null` it won't remember anything, and will start again from the start of the file.

Comment: After Restart logstash, **docs.count**  increasing and also **docs.deleted** counts increasing.